# IDLE 3 not printing on correct syntax

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

help here...my idle3 suddenly not working on print command. I have the following error, any clue to fix it? where's the problem?

```
>>> print("Hello World")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print("Hello World")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 374, in write
    self.stream.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1344, in write
    raise TypeError('must be str, not ' + type(s).__name__)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

system info:

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
```

Comment: If a Python application suddenly alters behavior, then something suddenly changed (got corrupted) in either the OS, Python, or the app.  If the mal-function is consistent, you could tell the difference between the latter to by trying the `print` in python started in the terminal.  But I would re-install Python (and on linux, the add-on package for tkinter and IDLE, if separate).  3.4.3 was released 2015-02-25 and 3.4.4 on 2015-12-21.  I would just upgrade to the latter if you can.

Comment: If you do not have to stick with 3.4, I would upgrade to 3.5 or 3.6, though I realize that this is harder of linux than on Windows or OSX.  I looked at the traceback some more.  It seems that Python is erroneously calling codecs to turn the print string into encoded bytes.  IDLE wants the string to be a string.  The .write method that raised `Typeerror` was executed in the user process before anything was sent to the socket connecting to the IDLE process.  If the python code is not corrupted, perhaps some setting somewhere was changed, perhaps an environmental variable.